# How to write simple MySQL workbench query

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have 1 table with 3 columns.
id (auto_increment), column0 , column1 like this:

```
+----+--------+---------+
| id | column0| column1 |
+----+--------+---------+
| 1  | 1.1111 | 0.1111  |
| 2  | 1.2222 | 0.2222  |
| 3  | 1.3333 | 0.3333  |
| 4  | 1.4444 | 0.4444  |
| .  | 1.5555 | 0.5555  |
+----+--------+---------+
```

I would like to SELECT this:

```
+--------+---------+
| column0| column1 |
+--------+---------+
| 1.1111 | 0.2222  |
| 1.2222 | 0.3333  |
| 1.3333 | 0.4444  |
| 1.4444 | 0.5555  |
| 1.5555 | 0.5555  |
+--------+---------+
```

How can I connect this two query into one query?
Can somebody write code for my please.

```
SELECT column0 FROM table;
```

and second query

```
SELECT column1 FROM table where id >1
union all
(SELECT column1 FROM table
ORDER BY id DESC 1);
```

Comment: No. What is there linking 1.1111 and 0.2222? Or any of the other values? In fact, you must have some logic behind this. Is it simply to take two resultsets and put them next to each other?

Comment: You also marked this as mysql-workbench, is this because you only care about the output, not the query as such? If so, copy and paste!

Comment: Values are not linked. Every time values will be diferent. I would like to have one query not two. How to connect this two query in one query?

Comment: Are you just wanting to offset the right hand column by -1 and then repeat the last value to any subsequent rows? That's what it appears. However in some respects it just seems like you want to modify the data rather than read it. The question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Use a self-JOIN

```
SELECT t1.column0, IFNULL(t2.column1, t1.column1) AS column1
FROM table AS t1
LEFT JOIN table AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id - 1
```

The `LEFT JOIN` and `IFNULL` are needed to handle the last row. You could also do it with a `UNION`

```
SELECT t1.column0, t2.column1
FROM table AS t1
INNER JOIN table AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id - 1
UNION
(SELECT column0, column1
 FROM table
 ORDER BY id DESC
 LIMIT 1)
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a96dd/3)

Note that this only works if there are no gaps in the `id` sequence. Finding the next row when there are gaps is more complicated. You can search SO for solutions that show how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If I follow you correctly, you want to return column0 or one row and column1 of the next row as a single record, but there is no "key" that links them, other than the logical "next sorted row".

If that is correct, try this.

```
select t1.column0, t2.column1 from
(select @t1row := @t1row + 1 as t1row, x1.column0 from (select @t1row := 0) as r1, tablex as x1 order by id) as t1,
(select @t2row := @t2row + 1 as t2row, x2.column1 from (select @t2row := 0) as r2, tablex as x2 where x2.id != (select min(x3.id) from tablex as x3) order by id) as t2
where t1.t1row = t2.t2row;
```

This should return:

```
column0 column1
1.1111  0.2222
1.2222  0.3333
1.3333  0.4444
1.4444  0.5555
```

But that leaves us without column0 of the "last" row and column1 of the "first" row.  Handling that is based on what you want to accomplish.
1) Do not include them
2) Return one more row linking last.column0 with first.column1
3) Return one row of with last.column0 linked to a null column1 and another row with a null column0 linked to first.column1

If #1, you are actually done.

If #2, add this union clause to the query above:

```
union
select x1.column0, x2.column1
from tablex as x1, tablex as x2, (select min(xi.id) as minid, max(xi.id) as maxid from tablex as xi) as x3
where x1.id = x3.maxid and x2.id = x3.minid
```

You get:

```
column0 column1
1.1111  0.2222
1.2222  0.3333
1.3333  0.4444
1.4444  0.5555
1.5555  0.1111
```

And if #3, add these union clauses to the query above:

```
union
select x1.column0, null as column1 from tablex as x1 where x1.id = (select max(xi.id) from tablex as xi)
union
select null as column0, x2.column1 from tablex as x2 where x2.id = (select min(xi.id) from tablex as xi)
```

And you get (you can resort them however you want):

```
column0 column1
1.1111  0.2222
1.2222  0.3333
1.3333  0.4444
1.4444  0.5555
1.5555
        0.1111
```

Enjoy!